# Reading sections of a txt file in C#

Tags: c#

I have a bunch of Powershell scripts which are executed and the full transcript is saved in a `.log` file in a specific location. I can read the `.log` file using:

```
string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\install.log");
foreach (string line in text)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

In this `.log` file, there is a lot of text and what I am trying to do is read specific sections of the `.log` file and do operations based on those. So for example the `.log` file contains something like this:

```
Executing script no. 1
#####LOTS OF POWERSHELL OUTPUT LINES HERE#####
Executing script no. 2
#####LOTS OF POWERSHELL OUTPUT LINES HERE#####
```

What I want to be able to do is read the text from `Executing script no. 1` and up until `Executing script no. 2` and then do some operations accordingly. And then move on to `script no. 2` and then so on.

Also, something to note here is that the `.log` file is being updated as the Powershell scripts are being executed. So when I start reading the `.log` file, it continues being updated until all the scripts have been executed and I see: `Transcript ended` at the end of the `.log` file.

How can I read the `.log` file in sections here?

Comment: Is there something unambiguous in the file that you can search for to find the start and end of the portion(s) that you're interested in?

Comment: How big are those files? Usually log files are not short and reading all the content in memory is not a good idea

Comment: @Steve The .log file is actually the transcript from Powershell scripts and the maximum it can reach is about 6000 lines.

Comment: @MatthewWatson I have the name writen at the top whenever a new script is executed so I can use something like `line.Contains("TEXT");` to filter that out. But I can't figure out how to read sections while the file is being updated

Answer (score 5):

You can approach your problem with this pattern

```
List<string> section = new List<string>();
foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"D:\install.log"))
{
    if (line.StartsWith("Executing script no"))
    {
        ProcessSection(section);
        section = new List<string>();
    }
    section.Add(line);

}

// Process the last section....
ProcessSection(section);
```

First, do not load all lines together in memory but read one by one accumulating them in a List of strings that represents the content of a section.
Then when you find the line that start the section pass everything to your processing code and restart with a new section data

```
void ProcessSection(List<string> sectionData)
{
    if(sectionData.Count == 0)
       return;

    // now you can loop over the strings in sectionData or
    // rejoin everything with
    // string.Join(Environment.NewLine,sectionData);
}
```

But, from your comment below, it seems that another process is writing to the file while you try to read it. In this context, File.ReadLines could fail because it will try to lock the file making impossible to the other process the write operation. (Or failing itself because it cannot lock the file).

In this context your need to read line by line in a different way

```
using (var fs = new FileStream("D:\\install.log", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite, 0x1000, FileOptions.SequentialScan))
using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        // as above
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question with a bit more information that might be relevant. The .log file is not complete and it continues being updated as the scripts are executed. My WPF app in which I am doing this is there to kind of show a summary of the scripts.

Comment: Will it be a good idea to put this in a `Do While` until `Transcript Ended` is read. This is because the `.log` file is being updated and the Transcript Ended means that the file is now completed so won't I need to update `System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"D:\install.log")` @Steve

Comment: Yes, whatever stops the reading you need to call again ProcessSection to process the last section, So just when the loop ends (no more lines) you could call again ProcessSection with the last data

Comment: But wait,... if some other process is writing to the file while this code tries to read it you will get a locking problem. You need to replace ReadLines with a different way to read file. Opening the stream in read only mode

Comment: I was thinking that since the file is being constantly updated, will this have an effect on the `ProcessSection`? Because for a particular section, I'm checking if certain conditions are met and that's updating the frontend of the WPF app. Will this end up executing it over and over for `executing script no.1` for example? If this does, will a better approach be to redirect the Powershell standartoutput to C# and then read from that? 
`using (StreamReader streamread = PowershellInstall.StandardOutput) { string result = streamread.ReadLine(); } `

Comment: Not sure if reading from standard input will change anything in the logic above. It should be the same. However, perhaps you need to keep the count of the line of the last section. This could be necessary if you start reading the last section while the PS process has not yet finished to write. You probably will reach the current end of file but the closure line (or even other lines) are missing. This scenario will force you to restart reading the file again. Perhaps it is better to wait the PS process to end

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242525/discussion-between-scripter0083-and-steve).

Answer (score 0):

you can use the IndexOf() fucntion to get the starting point of your scripts and extract the part from inbetween

```
string[] text = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"D:\install.log");
int start = text.IndexOf("Executing script no. 1")
int end   = text.IndexOf("Executing script no. 2")
string scriptOneOutput = text.Substring(start , end-start);
//now scriptOneOutput  should only contain the output from script one and you can process it
```

Comment: This will read all lines into memory at once. It might cause issues on larger files.